# How to animate on event in javascript using requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, socket.io, dom-events, requestanimationframe

I am using `requestAnimationFrame` in my Javascript app. The client side listens to an event sent from the server. Then the client starts to animate as it receives the event and in the callback the global client side variables are updated. (Socket is from 'socket.io')

```
const raf = window.requestAnimationFrame
  || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
  || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
  || window.oRequestAnimationFrame
  || window.msRequestAnimationFrame
  || function(callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
  };

let start = false;
let cp;

socket.on('init', function(data) {
  if (data) {
    start = true;
    cp = data.user;
  }
}

function animate() {
  // Do animation()
  cp.render();
}

if (start) {
  console.log('started animation');
  raf(animate);
}
```

But my code will never reach the block inside the last if expression, which means it doesn't print out `started animation`.

If I move `raf(animate)` out of the if clause it starts to animate however in this case if the `init` event hasn't been received I get an error saying that `cp` is `undefined`, so `cp.render()` is invalid. I can still animate but it is kind of annoying to see the error. How can I start animation only when the client receives the `init` event?

Comment: Just move the "if (start){ ... }" part inside the socket 'init' callback. The way you wrote it, it's probably executed before the 'init' callback.

Comment: @AliceOualouest Thanks that solved my problem.